# LWJGL method with keyboard input does not work in game loop

Tags: java, methods, lwjgl

I'm trying to make a game in java and I'm using LWJGL. So I'm able to move a quad around the screen using arrow keys and it works very nicely. Although the code for that is in the `Main` constructor, which works but it doesn't look very nice. So I decided to put it in a method and call the method within the `Main` constructor to save some space in the constructor. However when I put the code in a method, and call it, the function doesn't work. The cube won't move when I press the arrow keys.

This is my move method(which doesn't do anything when called in the main constructor):

```
public static void moveSquare(float x, float y, float speed, int deltaTime){
    if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_RIGHT)){
        x += speed * deltaTime;
    } 
    if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_LEFT)){
        x -= speed * deltaTime;
    }
    if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_UP)){
        y -= speed * deltaTime;
    }
    if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_DOWN)){
        y += speed * deltaTime;
    }
```

Here is my Main constructor where the game loops is. Some instances that i have are float x, float y, float speed, int width, and int height. just in case you see them referenced in the code and wonder where they came from.

```
public Main(){
    Display.setTitle("Squares!");
    try {
        Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(800,600));
        Display.create();
    } catch (LWJGLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    initGL();

    while(!Display.isCloseRequested()){

        int deltaTime = getDelta();

        drawSquare(x, y, width, height);
        moveSquare(x, y, speed, deltaTime);

        initClock();
        Display.update();
        GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        Display.sync(64); 
    } 

    Display.destroy();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A static method belongs to class, not to the objects. If you would like to access a non static field within your static method like x, y, speed... it would give you an error. But what you are actually doing here is passing a couple parameters to your move method which is doing a couple thing with them doesn't really matter what because that will only modify those copies within your method.

Let's say you have a `Square` class and you want to make it move with a move method that should not be static

```
public void move(float dt){
    //move stuff here
}
```

You don't even have to pass arguments only delta time because every square object will have its own copy(if not static) and move will use those.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. @Angel Garcia